# Java program to demonstrate abstract BankAccount class and SavingsAccount subclass

Tags: java

This week I was tasked with writing an abstract BankAccount class and a SavingsAccount class which extends BankAccount. I have written out the code as the assignment asks and it seems to compile perfectly. I now must write a driver to test the two classes and here is where I am stuck.. Just to be clear I'm not asking anyone to write it for me, I want to eventually be able to do this all on my own. I'm just asking for a little guidance. (I've scheduled one on one time with my instructor and he has cancelled twice)

I basically am wondering how to write the driver class for these two classes.
Are my classes missing anything in terms of fields or methods? How do you seasoned programmers plan out this kind of stuff?

Any suggestions you may have would be appreciated!

```
public abstract class BankAccount
{
  double balance;
  int numOfDeposits;
  int numOfWithdraws;
  double interestRate;
  double annualInterest;
  double monSCharges;
  double amount;
  double monInterest;

  //constructor accepts arguments for balance and annual interest rate
  public BankAccount(double bal, double intrRate)
  {
    balance = bal;
    annualInterest = intrRate;
  }

  //sets amount
   public void setAmount(double myAmount)
    {
        amount = myAmount;
    }

  //method to add to balance and increment number of deposits
  public void deposit(double amountIn)
  {
    balance = balance + amountIn;
    numOfDeposits++;
  }

  //method to negate from balance and increment number of withdrawals
  public void withdraw(double amount)
  {
    balance = balance - amount;
    numOfWithdraws++;
  }

  //updates balance by calculating monthly interest earned
  public double calcInterest()
  {
    double monRate;

    monRate= interestRate / 12;
    monInterest = balance * monRate;
    balance = balance + monInterest;
    return balance;
  }

  //subtracts services charges calls calcInterest method sets number of withdrawals and deposits
  //and service charges to 0
  public void monthlyProcess()
  {
    calcInterest();
    numOfWithdraws = 0;
    numOfDeposits = 0;
    monSCharges = 0;
  }

  //returns balance
  public double getBalance()
  {
    return balance;
  }

  //returns deposits
  public double getDeposits()
  {
    return numOfDeposits;
  }

  //returns withdrawals
  public double getWithdraws()
  {
    return numOfWithdraws;
  }
}
```

and the subclass

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount
{
  //sends balance and interest rate to BankAccount constructor
  public SavingsAccount(double b, double i)
  {
    super(b, i);
  }

  //determines if account is active or inactive based on a min acount balance of $25
  public boolean isActive()
  {
    if (balance >= 25)
      return true;
    return false;
  }

  //checks if account is active, if it is it uses the superclass version of the method
  public void withdraw()
  {
    if(isActive() == true)
    {
      super.withdraw(amount);
    }
  }

  //checks if account is active, if it is it uses the superclass version of deposit method
  public void deposit()
  {
    if(isActive() == true)
    {
      super.deposit(amount);
    }
  }

  //checks number of withdrawals adds service charge
  public void monthlyProcess()
  {
    if(numOfWithdraws > 4)
      monSCharges++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue ?? Did you want us to verify the code

Comment: So you want to know how to write unit test for this right?

Comment: Add the @Override annotation on the methods that are supposed to override methods of the superclass. This will help you spot two bugs of your class. And you should never silently do nothing like you're doing: if the account isn't active and someone tries to deposit or withdraw, an exception should be thrown.

Comment: Please post your `Driver`. I'm guessing that it's trying to instantiate the abstract class.

Comment: Yes, I basically want to know how to write the driver for these classes. I just don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A driver or runner class is usually a class with a main method in which you can run code. Basically...

```
public class TestDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Run your code here...
    }
}
```

What you probably need to do is create a few SavingsAccount objects inside of it, and show that the methods it implements work.

If this is a school assignment, you may need to get more specific details from your instructor if you are not understanding the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I got that so far, I'm more confused with how I get the amounts to the proper methods from the driver class. So far I have a program that prompts for a choice such as deposit, withdrawal etc. I then have a switch/case statement ready to perform actions based on what the user puts in. For example if they select deposit, it asks how much. After that is where I'm stuck.

Comment: As a starter, assuming that after a user enters an amount for the deposit, the SavingsAccount object gets that data, then you could call its getDeposits() method and print it out for the user. In general, every time a user does something to their SavingsAccount you print it out so the user sees the results of their transaction.

Comment: I just wanted to add I tried creating a setAmount method in the SavingsAccount class and sending the entered amount from the driver class to the setAmount method in the SavingsAccount class and I keep getting an error regarding static and non static method references

Comment: Sounds like you may be calling SavingsAccounts methods directly inside main(...). this is not allowed. You need to create a SavingsAccounts object inside main(...) and then call the methods from that object.